# Find a sequence of functions $\{g_n\}$ in $C([0,1])$ so that $\overline{\{g_n\}}$ is compact, but $g_n$ does not converge uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, uniform-convergence

Consider the space $C([0,1])$ equipped with the uniform norm.
Find a sequence of functions $\{g_n\}$ in $C([0,1])$ so that $\overline{\{g_n\}}$ is compact, but $g_n$ does not converge uniformly.

I can't seem to find a sequence of function that satisfy the above statement. I started off by finding a non-uniform convergence sequence and work from there but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814293/does-pointwise-convergence-of-continuous-functions-on-a-compact-set-to-a-continu

Comment: Do you mean that the closure of the sequence $\{g_n\}$ is compact in the space $C[0,1]$ with its max-norm?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each $n\in\mathbb N$ and each $x\in[0,1]$, define $g_n(x)=(-1)^n$.

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think $g_n(x)$ is continuous..

Comment: I could swear that every constant function is continuous.

Comment: My bad. Thank you!