# Metric space compactness

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Consider the space $C([0,1])$ equipped with the uniform norm. 
 Find a sequence of functions $\{g_n\}$ in $C([0,1])$ so that $\overline{\{g_n\}}$ is compact, but $g_n$ does not converge uniformly.

I'm confused about $\overline{\{g_n\}}$ and how to prove its compactness

Thanks!

Comment: Would $|sin(kx)|$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$ fit in your problem?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157437/find-a-sequence-of-functions-g-n-in-c0-1-so-that-overline-g-n?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

$g_n\equiv 1$ for $n$ even and $g_n\equiv 0$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: Boring yet effective..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Is $g_n(x)=exp(exp(sin(cos(artan(exp(x))))))$ for $n$ even and $g_n(x)=x^{216}-34x^675+130$ for $n$ odd less boring? -:)

Comment: then you’d need more of an argument for continuity.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that for some given $g_n$, $\overline{\{g_n\}}$ is compact, we can show that the $g_n$ are uniformly bounded and equicontinuous. Arzela-Ascoli then implies that $\{g_n\}$ is precompact in $C([0,1])$, which gives what you want (i.e., compactness of the closure). So, the work will be in finding a sequence of such $g_n$ which do not converge.

Edit: I suppose I used "work" rather loosely above. Combine the given argument with the choice of $g_n$'s suggested and that should do it.