# What is wrong with the following proof that seems to prove pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

**I know uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence and not the other way around. Then what is wrong with the following proof that seems to prove that pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence?**

Lef $\{f_n(x)\}_n$ be a pointwise convergent sequence of functions in $C[a,b]$. Let the pointwise limit be f(t) for every t. Then $\{f_n(x)\}_n$ is Cauchy that is $\forall \epsilon >0 ,\exists N$ such that if $n,m>N$, $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon/2$

Passing to the sup:
$\text{Sup}_{x \in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\le\epsilon/2$

Taking the limit $m\to \infty$ in the last inequality : $\text{Sup}_{x \in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le\epsilon/2<\epsilon $ Which is the definition of uniform convergence.

**The definitions I am using:**

$f_n:I\subset \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$,$f:A\subset I\to \mathbb{R}$

1. $f_n \to f$, that is $f_n$ converges pointwise to f if $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x) \forall x \in A$
   $\iff \forall x \in A \forall \epsilon>0 \exists N $such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon , \forall n>N$
2. $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\text{Sup}_{x \in A}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0 $
   $\iff  \forall \epsilon>0 \exists N $such that $\text{Sup}_{x \in A}|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon, \forall n>N$.

I got this idea from (**) below, in the proof of the completeness of $C[a,b]$ with respect to the uniform metric that my professor did. There is a step in which she took the limit $m\to \infty$  of the inequality: $\text{Sup}_{t \in [a,b]}|f_n(t)-f_m(t)|< \epsilon $.

**The proof that my professor of the completeness of $C[a,b]$ with respect to the uniform metric did was:**

Let $\{f_n(t)\}_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $C[a,b]$ Then $\forall \epsilon >0 ,\exists N$ such that if $n,m>N$, $|f_n(t)-f_m(t)|<Sup|f_n(t)-f_m(t)|<\epsilon$ ...(*)

For each fixed $t\in[a,b]$: $\{f_n(t)\}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.
Because $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, $\exists \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(t) = f(t) \in \mathbb{R}$

So we have built a function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$, now we have to see that it is the limit of the f_n with respect to the uniform distance defined on $C[a,b]$ and that it is continuous.

In order to find that the function f(x) built as the pointwise limit of f_n(x) for each x, is also the limit with respect to the uniform distance, (that is that $\sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0)$we take the limit $m\to \infty$ in (*):$\sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| )<\epsilon$ : $\text{Sup}_{x \in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \epsilon$..(**)

That is we have $\forall \epsilon >0 ,\exists N$ such that if $n,m>N$, $\text{Sup}_{x \in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \epsilon$ (this can be made into <\epsilon working with \epsilon/2 at the beginning), which means $f$ is the limit of the f_n with respect to the uniform distance defined on $C[a,b]$.

To show $f \in C[a,b]$:
$|f(t)-f(t_0)|<|f(t)-f_n(t)|+|f_n(t)-f_n(t_0)|+|f_n(t_0)-f(t_0)| <3\epsilon$, where $|f(t)-f_n(t)|<\epsilon $and $|f(t_0)-f_n(t_0)|<\epsilon$ because of the pointwise convergence of $f_n$ and $|f_n(t)-f_n(t_0)|<\epsilon $ because of the continuity of $f_n$ at $t_0$

Comment: When you say : "passing to the sup : $\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq \varepsilon /2"$. This is not true because the $N$ before depend on $x$.

Comment: @Surb $|f(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon/2$ is true for each x, then it sure must be true for the greatest $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| $which is the Sup, I don't see why$  N$ depending on $x$  may influence that, perhaps you could provide an explicit example? And isn't it the same my professor did in  ( * ), (**) below?

Comment: Fix $\varepsilon >0$ and $x\in \mathbb R$. Then $(f_n(x))$ is Cauchy, therefore, there is $N=N(x,\varepsilon )$ s.t. $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\varepsilon /2$ whenever $n,m\geq N$. Now, if you change the $x$, you change the $N$, therefore, you don't have $|f_n(t)-f_m(t)|<\varepsilon /2$ for all $t\in [a,b]$ whenever $n,m\geq N$, and thus you can't take the supremum. For $(*)$  and $(**)$ it's not clear what you try to prove, but it's not true if you only suppose that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise...

Comment: $|f(x)-f_m(x)|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$ may not be true for each $x$ if you fix $m$.

Comment: In the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1814468/75923) to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1814293/75923) I encountered counterexample: "The sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\min(1,n|x-1/n|)$ converges to $1$ pointwise on the interval $[0,1]$, yet the convergence is not uniform."

Comment: @Surb Can't I take $n, m >\text{max}\{N(x,\epsilon),x\in[a,b]\}$?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO : No because this may be $\infty $. A very simple example : take $f_n(x)=(-nx+1)\boldsymbol 1_{[0,1/n]}(x)$. Fix $\varepsilon >0$ and $x>0$. Then take $N_{x,\varepsilon }=\inf\{n\in\mathbb N\mid x>\frac{1}{n}\}+1$. Then $|f_n(x)-f_{n+m}(x)|=0<\varepsilon $ for all $n\geq N_{x,\varepsilon }$. Finally, if $x=0$, take $N_{x,\varepsilon }=1$. Therefore, for all $\varepsilon >0$, all $x\in [0,1]$ you have that $|f_n(x)+f_{n+m}(x)|<\varepsilon $  for all $n\geq N_{x,\varepsilon }$ and all $m\in \mathbb N$, however $\sup_{x\in [0,1]}N_{x,\varepsilon }=\infty $.

Comment: @Surb Im'trying to understand your example. To make it easier I take $x=1/\alpha, \alpha>1, \alpha\in\mathbb{N}$ then $N_{1/\alpha,\epsilon}=inf\{n\in\mathbb{N}| x>\alpha\}=\alpha+1$ (so why complicating it with the inf?) then $Sup N_{1/\alpha,\epsilon} =Sup\{\alpha +1: \alpha>1, \alpha\in\mathbb{N}\} =\infty$ Is this how you prove that the Sup is $\infty$?.

Comment: I don't know how to prove$ |f_n(x)-f_{n+m}(x)|=0$ starting from $n>N_{1/ \alpha,\epsilon}>0$. I even drew $f_n $and $f_{n+m}$. I doesn't seem to be zero, there is a gap between the two lines

Comment: Yes for your first comment. Now, $f_n(x)=0$ if $x>1/n$, therefore $|f_n(x)-f_{n+m}(x)|=0$ if $x>N_x$ (since by definition of $N$, $f_n(x)=0$ for $n\geq N_x$). @J.C.VegaO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make a counterexample graphically.
Define a function $f_n(x)$ on the interval $[0,1]$ by plotting $y = f_n(x),$
where the graph of this function consists of a straight line segment from
$(0,0)$ to $(2^{-n},1),$
a straight line segment from $(2^{-n},1)$ to $(2(2^{-n}),0),$
and finally a straight line segment along the $x$ axis connecting
$(2(2^{-n}),0)$ to $(1,0).$

For large $n$ this function is a constant $0$ over most of the interval, but there is a sharp triangular "bump" at the left end of the interval whose highest point is at $y=1.$

Now at $x=0,$ we always have $f_n(x) = f_n(0) = 0.$ The sequence $0,0,0,\ldots$ converges to zero, so we have convergence at $x=0.$

For any $x > 0,$ you can always find $N$ such that $2(2^{-N}) < x.$
Then for any $n > N$ you have $f_n(x) = 0,$ so we have convergence at that value of $x.$

So we have pointwise convergence to the function $f(x) = 0$ on $[0,1].$

But no matter how large you make $n,$ there is still a triangular bump at the left end of the graph and the highest point on that bump still hits the line $y=1.$

So consider $\epsilon = \frac12.$ For what $n$ is it the case that
$\sup_{x \in [0,1]} \lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert < \epsilon = \frac12$?

The answer is there is no such $n,$ because for every $n,$

$$ \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert = 1. $$

Therefore we do not have uniform convergence.

Comment: I wanted to see how beginning with $|f_n(x)-f_(x)|<\epsilon$ and taking an N that depends on x,$Sup|f_n(x)-f_(x)|<\epsilon$  is false. You already showed that $Sup|f_n(x)-f_(x)|<\epsilon$ is false Now, before that I needed  $|f_n(x)-f_(x)|<\epsilon$ for n>N to be true. Is it?  and where is the dependence of N on x?. I got the graphical picture, still not seeing how my N is dependent on x

Comment: As I wrote, "For any $x>0$, you can always find $N$." But you have to choose $x$ first before you decide what $N$ is. The smaller you make $x$, the larger $N$ needs to be. That's how $N$ depends on $x.$ If you choose $N$ first, then there's always an $x$ for which this $N$ is no good, for example $x = 2^{-N-1}$, where if $n = N+1 > N$ then $f_n(x) = 1.$

Comment: I think I got it,  the descending line of the triangular bump has to intersect the line $x=x_N$ for all of the inequality to be true for all subsequent  $n>N$. This descending line has as equation $ y=-2^Nx +2$, whose intersection with $y=\epsilon$ yields  $x_N=2^{-N}(2-\epsilon)$. Inverting it $N=log((2-\epsilon)/x_N)/log2$, which shows an explicit dependence of N on both x and $\epsilon$

Comment: Just something else, in (*)the professor takes the limit $m\to \infty$ in $\text{Sup}_{x \in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|< \epsilon$ so that $\text{Sup}_{x \in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f_(x)|\le \epsilon$. How does the limit  gets to enter inside the sup? I don't recall any explicit theorem about this and why does the inequality becomes non strict?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: You can only do that if $f_n\to f$ uniformly (it's not so clear what your teacher tries to prove, could you please write precisely the statement ?)... So, if it's the case, notice that $\|f\|_\infty := \sup_{x\in [a,b]}|f(x)|$ is a norm on $\mathcal C[a,b]$ (prove it if it's not clear). Therefore, by triangle inequality, $|\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty -\|f_n-f\|_\infty |\leq \|f-f_m\|_\infty $, and thus taking $m\to \infty $ gives the wished result.

Comment: In order to find that the function $f(x)$ built as the pointwise limit of $f_n(x)$ for each x, is also the limit with respect to the uniform distance, (that is that $\sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0)$we take the limit $m\to \infty$ in (*):$\sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| )<\epsilon$ , which yields $\text{sup}_{x \in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \epsilon$. So she's getting "inside the sup" when taking the limit of the right-hand side

Comment: Now I recall the norm is a continuos function, so I can get see it as a composition of continuous functions, therefore the $\lim_m||f_n(x)-f_m(x)||=||\lim_m (f_n(x)-f_m(x)) ||$

Answer (score 1):

> Passing to the sup:
> $\text{Sup}_{x \in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\le\epsilon/2$

Here you mean of course that this is satisfied for all $n, m \ge N$.

This is not true. You know that $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists N$ such that if $n,m>N$, $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon/2$, but $N$ depends on $x$.

As an example take $[a,b] = [0,1]$ and $f_n(x) = x^n$. Then we get
$$\lvert f_n(x) - f_m(x) \rvert  = \lvert x^n- x^m \rvert.$$

Let $\delta < 1$ and $x \in (0,1)$. We want to find an index $N$ such that
$$\lvert x^n- x^m \rvert < \delta \text{ for all } n,m \ge N \tag{1}$$

Clearly we must have $\lvert x^N- x^m \rvert < \delta$ for all $m \ge N$. Since $x^m \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$, this requires $x^N < \delta$. But if $x^N < \delta$, then $\lvert x^n- x^m \rvert = x^N \lvert x^{n-N}- x^{m-N} \rvert \le x^N < \delta$. Thus $(1)$ is satisfied iff
$$x^N < \delta . \tag{2}$$
But $(2)$ means $N\ln x < \ln \delta$. Because $\ln x < 0$ for $x \in (0,1)$, we get
$$N > r(x) = \ln \delta / \ln x . \tag{3}$$
But $r(x) > 0$ because $\ln \delta  < 0$. Since $\ln x \to 0$ as $x \to 1$, we see that $r(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to 1$.  This shows that $N$ depends on $x$. In fact, $N(x) \to \infty$ as  $x \to 1$.

Comment: any explicit example of how taking an N that depends on x, makes the Sup inequality false? I am no very convinced of this

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: see my last comment under your original post.

Comment: How does it follow from this that $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} \lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert < \epsilon$ is false?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO In this particular example, where $f_n(x) = x^n$, we find that $f(1) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ everywhere in the interval $[0,1).$ So $\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert = 0$ when $x = 1$ and $\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert = x^n$ when $0\leq x<1.$ Now the limit of $x^n$ as $x\to 1$ is $1,$ so $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} \lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert = 1.$

Comment: @J.C.VegaO It shows that there cannot exist an index $N$ such that $\text{Sup}_{x \in [a,b]}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\le\epsilon/2$ for all $n, m \ge N$. The latter would imply that $\lvert f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\le\epsilon/2$ for all $n, m \ge N$ and $x \in [0,1]$. But  for any given $N$ we have $r(x) > N$ for $x$ sufficiently  close to $1$ -  although we need $N > r(x)$ for these $x$.