# Alternative proof for Dini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am attempting to prove [Dini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) without consulting the exiting proof for it. However, in my proof I do not use the fact that $f_n(x)$ is an increasing sequence for a given x. So I am certain my proof is wrong but I need help to spot the flaw. Basically I prove the following hypothesis:

**Hypothesis:** If $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise on a compact set $K$, and both $f_n$ and $f$ are continuous on $K$ then $f_n$ uniformly converges to $f$.

**Proof:**
$f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise on compact set $K$:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\forall\epsilon > 0, ~~ \forall x \in K, ~~ \exists N_x \in \mathbb{N},~~ s.t.~~ n \geq N_x \rightarrow |f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon 
\end{equation}

$f_x(x)$ and $f_n$ are both continuous on the compact set $K$ and hence both are uniformly continuous on the compact set $K$:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\forall\epsilon > 0, ~~ \exists \delta>0,~~ s.t.~~|x-y|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\forall\epsilon > 0, ~~ \exists \bar{\delta}>0,~~ s.t.~~|x-y|<\bar{\delta} \rightarrow |f_n(x)-f_n(y)| < \epsilon 
\end{equation}
I define $\delta_{min}=\{\delta, \bar{\delta}\}$, then using $(1)-(3), ~~ \forall y \in V_{\delta_{min}}(x)$ and $n \geq N_x$ we have:
\begin{align}\tag{4}
|f_n(y)-f(y)| &= |f_n(y)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f(x)+f(x)-f(y)| \\ &< |f_n(y)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(y)|\\&< \frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}= \epsilon
\end{align}

Basically what $(4)$ says is that for all $y$ in the $\delta_{min}$ neighborhood of x (ball of radius $\delta_{min}$), there exists a single $N_x$ for which $|f_n(y)-f(y)|$ could be arbitrarily small.

Now we can construct an open cover for $K$ using $V_{\delta_{min}(x)}$ as follow:
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
K \subset \cup_{x \in K}V_{\delta_{min}(x)}
\end{equation}

Because $K$ is compact the above open cover has a finite subcover ([Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)), consequently
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
K \subset \cup_{i=1}^{N}V_{\delta_{min}(x_i)}
\end{equation}

As we argued in $(4)$ for all $y \in V_{\delta_{min}(x_i)} $ there exists a single $N_{x_i}$ such that $n \geq N_{x_i}$ then $|f_n(y)-f(y)| < \epsilon$. Hence, for $N=max(N_{x_1}, \cdots, N_{x_N})$ when $n \geq N$ then  $|f_n(y)-f(y)| < \epsilon,$ $\forall y \in  \cup_{i=1}^{N}V_{\delta_{min}(x_i)}$.

Finally, from the above and $(6)$ we can conclude that
\begin{equation}
\forall\epsilon > 0, ~~ \exists N=max(N_{x_1}, \cdots, N_{x_N}),~~ when~~ n \geq N \rightarrow |f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon, \forall x \in K, 
\end{equation}
hence uniform convergence.

I need help to the logical flaw in my proof above as I know the hypothesis is wrong. I have also found this [counter-example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814293/does-pointwise-convergence-of-continuous-functions-on-a-compact-set-to-a-continu) for the proof but still unable to spot the problem.

Comment: I believe the error is that $\overline{\delta}$ depends on $n$, right?

Comment: Can you visualize what is $\delta_{min}$ in a counter-example?

Comment: @Dabouliplop great point!
I can see $\bar{\delta}$ could depend on n but need to try to visualize it to see where exactly the problem is.

Comment: Great question, and thanks for all the effort you put into it.

Comment: A bunch of counterexamples: take a continuous  function $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $f(1/2)=1.$ Then $f_n(x)= f(x^n)\to 0$ pointwise but $f_n(2^{-1/n})=1.$