# Terminology for "pointwise convergence on compact subsets"? (Sobolev spaces)

Tags: convergence-divergence, reference-request, terminology, sobolev-spaces

I am reading Lawrence C. Evans's book "Partial Differential Equations". I am on page 259 in section 5.2, *Sobolev spaces*. He writes the following:

> Let $\{u_m\}_{m\in\mathbb N},u\in W^{k,p}(U)$. We say $u_m$ converges to $u$ in $W^{k,p}(U)$, written $$u_m\to u ~~~~\text{in}~W^{k,p}(U)$$
> Provided
> $$\lim_{m\to\infty} \Vert u_m-u\Vert_{W^{k,p}(U)}=0$$
> We write
> $$u_m\to u~~~~\text{in}~W_{\text{loc}}^{k,p}(U)\tag{*}$$
> to mean
> $$u_m\to u~~~~\text{in}~W^{k,p}(V)\tag{**}$$
> For all $V\subset \subset U$.

---

**NOTATION:** $V\subset\subset U$ means that $V\subset \bar{V}\subset U$ and $\bar V$ is compact. $W^{k,p}(U)$ is a Sobolev space and $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{W^{k,p}(U)}$ is its associated norm.

---

### **My question:**

Is there standard terminology for the type of convergence in $(*)$? To me the terminology "local convergence" seems fitting, but this appears not to be standard. It is quite close to [compact convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence), however the convergence in each compact set $(**)$ in this case is not [uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) - instead of convergence W.R.T the $L^\infty$ norm, it is convergence with respect to the $W^{k,p}$ norm. Is convergence in the $L^\infty$ and $W^{k,p}$ norms equivalent on compact sets? I know that [pointwise and uniform convergence are not equivalent on compact sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814293/does-pointwise-convergence-of-continuous-functions-on-a-compact-set-to-a-continu).

Basically, is there standard terminology for "convergence in norm on compact subsets" ?

Comment: I would call it "local $W^{k,p}$ convergence." In general the "local" part means that you require the convergence to hold on all $V \subset\subset U$, but you still need to specify what type of convergence you require to hold on each $V$.

Comment: Aside.  Do we prefer notation $$V\subset\subset U\quad\text{or}\quad V \Subset U$$ `V\subset\subset U` or `V \Subset U` ?

Comment: @GEdgar $\subset\subset$ is what I saw in Evans's book. I wasn't even aware of the $\Subset $ symbol.